# Java Streams API: how to perform an operation inside the stream on the whole list result?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a way to use the stream result (`List<Integer>` in my case) to perform an operation inside the function on that list (all at once)

So instead of this:

```
var cardTypesToRemove = existingIds.stream()
                .filter(c -> !cardTypeIds.contains(c))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

repository.deleteBy(cardTypesToRemove);
```

Something like this (excuse me for pseudo code)

```
var cardTypesToRemove = existingIds.stream()
                .filter(c -> !cardTypeIds.contains(c))
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(repository.saveAll(resultList)));
```

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your actual problem? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? Why can't you just collect the stream and just then call that function?

Comment: of course I can call the result of the initial stream manipulation in another line of code separate, I'm asking if this can be done inside the same stream function.

Answer (score 0):

No. Just pass the result of the `collect` as a regular method parameter.

```
var cardTypesToRemove = repository.saveAll(
    existingIds.stream()
        .filter(c -> !cardTypeIds.contains(c))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So there's no way to use the stream result inside the same stream without actually iterating? That's a bummer. Then I guess its ++ lines of code outside the stream function.